# Raspberry Pi Debian tool for ping monitoring

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, ping, monitor

I'm looking for tool. I have some devices connected to local network: temperature controller, routers, NASs etc. Each device have static ip. I need tool to ping devices. When ping fails tool must send me an email. 
Need smile tool for slow Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 2):

You can setup such a tool with linux easily using shell scripts. Loop over your all static ip addresses with this code. You can define an external smtp server with ssmtp package and here is the [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/37061/132933) describing how you can do it. You can also create a cron job to schedule your script. Hope this helps you.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
ip_address="192.168.1.1"
if ping -c1 "$ip_address" &>/dev/null
then
    echo "success"
else
    echo "PING to $ip_address failed" | mail -s "ping error" someone@example.com
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tutorial on how to setup your pi with Nagios
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/turn-raspberry-pi-network-monitoring-tool/

here's how to setup email alerts:
https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/316105:setting-up-email-alerts-for-network-monitoring-with-nagios